# Visual Studio is it possible to break when a type is first used?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I've been handed this gigantic code base, written in C, that I need to step through and find a certain feature so I can reverse engineer and modify it.  Since this code is hundreds of thousands of lines long, you can imagine that this process is quite slow.  I have an idea for how to speed it along, but I don't know if it is possible.  I have something that resembles this:

```
struct A{
   /* some data */
};

struct B{
   A* a;
   /* some data */
};
/* note A and B are defined in different files */
```

I want Visual Studio to break when B->a is first assigned/modified on any arbitrary instance of B.  Is this possible to do in Visual Studio Professional 2012?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the constructor?

Comment: Sadly, it isn't that simple.  The constructor initializes that value to `NULL`, and other code later assigns that value.  I guess I could set a breakpoint to the constructor and step through it from that point onward which would help, but not quite get me what I want.

Comment: When it triggers you can set a memory breakpoint on `B->a` and then wait for that one to trigger.

Comment: @kichik I guess I'll have to do it that way.  Repost that as an answer so I can give you the reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint on the constructor for type `B` (or the equivalent of a constructor in your C code). When that triggers, you can set a memory breakpoint on `B->a` and wait for that one to trigger.

Comment: The OP wanted to break on access to *any* `B::a`. Setting data breakpoint is only possible on a *specific* `B::a` in a specific `B` object, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Yes, this will only work if there is a reasonable number of `B` instances.

Comment: @AnT my research is indicating that this isn't possible, but setting a breakpoint when the constructor is first called tells me where the instance is first created, and the second breakpoint gives me the data I need.  While it does't directly answer my question, it does give me a workaround that makes my question unnecessary, so I'm still accepting this.